# Test Pyodbc Connection Object

Tags: python, connection, timeout, pyodbc

I have a script which initiates a Pyodbc connection to a Teradata database when it starts. After 1h20 minutes, the script is reusing the connection object to execute a query on Teradata (using pandas). The query is very simple and I know it is correct because I have tested it manually. When the script executes it, I get the following error message:

```
oData = pandas.read_sql(oQuery, oConnexion)
```

> Error message: (,
>   DatabaseError("Execution failed on sql: SELECT
>   DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR\n        ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_PARAMETER\n
>   ,DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_PARAMETER_VALUE\n        FROM
>   AUDIT_VIEWS.AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_PARAMETER A\n        JOIN
>   AUDIT_VIEWS.AUDIT_DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR B ON
>   A.DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_KEY=B.DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_KEY\n
>   WHERE
>   DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR='DATA_COMPLETENESS_DNA_EXPORT_COUNTER_VS_CSV_DATA'\n
>   AND DATA_QUALITY_INDICATOR_PARAMETER='oMeasures';\n('HY000', 'The
>   driver did not supply an error!')\nunable to rollback",), )

Although it's not explicit, I'm thinking the execution failed because the connection object may have timed out (note that no time out is set when creating the connection object). Would you know a way to:

- Keep the connection object alive during the whole process?
- Test if the connection object is still valid prior executing a query?

Thanks

Comment: One solution I'm thinking about but it's not very elegant is to run a simple query prior executing the actual query I want to run. Maybe something simple like `select '1'` just to test if the connection is still open.
What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented the following workaround which confirms it was a timeout issue with the connection object. Before reusing the connection object I'm testing and reopen a connection if the test fails.

```
 import pyodbc
 try:
 #test current connection object in global variable
      oConnexion = oGlobalVariable['oConnexion']
      oCursor = oConnexion.cursor()
      oCursor.execute("select '1'")
      oCursor.close()
 except:
      #if test fails re-open connection
      oConnexionString = fGetParameterFile(pFileName="global_parameter.ini", pSectionName="AUDIT", pParameterName="oConnexionString")
      oConnexion = pyodbc.connect(oConnexionString, autocommit=True)
      oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
      oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
      oConnexion.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-8')
      oConnexion.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
      oGlobalVariable['oConnexion'] = oConnexion
      return oConnexion
 else:
      return oGlobalVariable['oConnexion']
```